# JDBC Template : MS SQL datetime column query

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a MS SQL DN with a table called 'Load' which has a column 'load_starttime' which is of type datetime. My query is trying to count the numbers of rows that have been inserted for a specific day. I followed this tutorial for [mapping a datetime via the jdbc template](http://justinjohnson.org/development/inserting-datetime-with-spring-jdbctemplate-and-namedparameterjdbctemplate/).

```
Date d = new Date("2014-02-06");
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
int count = template.queryForInt(
    "SELECT COUNT(load_starttime) FROM Load WHERE load_starttime=:load_starttime",
        new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(
            "load_starttime", 
            new java.sql.Date(d.getTime())
        ),
    Types.TIMESTAMP   
);
```

My current exception is

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT COUNT(load_starttime) FROM Load WHERE load_starttime=:load_starttime]; Unable to convert between org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource and JAVA_OBJECT.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource and JAVA_OBJECT.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:729)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:745)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:776)
```

The second part

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource and JAVA_OBJECT.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support.convert(Support.java:446)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setObjectBase(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:370)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setObject(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:668)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:365)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:642)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think is due to .

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
```

Try to do it with

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
```

JdbcTemplate only works with ?

> **JdbcTemplate** - this is the classic Spring JDBC approach and the most widely used. This is the "lowest level" approach and all other
>   approaches use a JdbcTemplate under the covers. Works well in a JDK
>   1.4 and higher environment.
>
> **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate** - wraps a JdbcTemplate to provide more convenient usage with named parameters instead of the traditional JDBC
>   "?" place holders. This provides better documentation and ease of use
>   when you have multiple parameters for an SQL statement. Works with JDK
>   1.4 and up.

And this is considered as a named parameter *load_starttime=:load_starttime*

Answer (score 0):

The `JdbcTemplate` class does not support named parameters. You have to use the 'NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' class for this task.
See bellow the source code to do what you want:

```java
    final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    final Date d = new Date("2014-02-06");
    int count = template.queryForObject(
            "SELECT COUNT(load_starttime) FROM Load WHERE load_starttime=:load_starttime",
            new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("load_starttime", new java.sql.Date(d.getTime())),
            Integer.class
    );
```